# converting a string to list of lists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, django

I have a list that i made using django and i passed it to `index.html` the problem is that i need to use it in the JavaScript content but it is passed as a string to it and I tried JSON.parse but I got error message

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'F', "[[0, False], [0"... is not valid JSON)

and here is the list:

```
[[0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], 
 [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], 
 [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], 
 [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], 
 [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False], 
 [2, True], [2, True]]
```

here is the html line:

```html
<div class="like-component" data-post-id="{{post.id}}" data-likes="{{likes}}"></div>
```

and here is the JavaScript part:

```
function renderlikeposts(){
  const likeComponents = document.querySelectorAll('.like-component');
  likeComponents.forEach(component => {
    const postId = component.dataset.postId;
    const list   = JSON.parse(component.dataset.likes);
    const likes  = component.dataset.likes[postId-1][0];
    const liked  = Boolean(component.dataset.likes[postId-1][1]);
    ReactDOM.render(<Like postId={postId} likes={likes} liked={liked} list={list} />, component);
  });
}
```

Comment: in Javascript, booleans are `true` and `false` ... not `True` and `False` ... therefore, the server is not sending JSON, or rather `component.dataset.likes` is not JSON

Comment: There no language named `java script` there is `java` or `javascript`. there is no hypothetical "scripting" language based on the java language

Comment: As pointed out `True` & `true` etc in Javascript are not the same thing,  if your text always looks like this, a simple hack is just to `JSON.parse(component.dataset.likes.toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup as @Jaromanda X mentioned, when we use JSON.parse it's  [constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). When it tries to execute the following:

```
JSON.parse(
  '[  [0, False],  [0, False],  [0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False], [0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[0, False],[2, True],[2, True]]',
);
```

It's encountering `False` and cannot convert it into valid JavaScript. When I change all your False/True value to `false`/`true` (valid JavaScript booleans) it goes through fine:

```
JSON.parse('[  [0, false],  [0, false],  [0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false], [0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[0, false],[2, true],[2, true]]')
```